# How to force plotly to display x axis numbers as categories?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a dataset where I'm referring to samples as numbers - when I try and do a bar graph using plotly (in JS) it's treating them as numbers and not as a label. How can I turn that off?

Comment: It's ugly, but so far I'm just adding &nbsp; to every entry - this works, but it's ugly.

Comment: Set the axes as Categorical: https://plotly.com/javascript/axes/#categorical-axes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can override plotly's axis auto-type routine by specifying the axis `type`. For example,

```
var data = [/* your data */];

var layout = {
   xaxis: { type: 'category' }
};

Plotly.plot('graph', data, layout);
```